# Eclipse is always on top

Tags: eclipse

My problem is that Eclipse is always on top. 
When I open Eclipse and I want to open other programs like for example Firefox by clicking their shortcut on the taskbar, the window opens up behind Eclipse.

Answer (score 40):

I'm using windows 7 and just encountered this problem.
I found the solution is to press 'Ctrl + Alt + Esc'.

Comment: Thanks. It solved my problem. All I did in the first place was to close Eclipse and open it... go figure.

Comment: Works fine in Windows 10, too. Thanks.

Comment: Save my life thanx

Comment: I had the opposite problem -- Eclipse was stuck *behind* everything else. This solved it! (Windows 10, BTW)

Comment: I have the same exact issue as OP, but the Ctrl+Alt+Esc key combo doesn't fix it for me. Eclipse is on top no matter what window I use. It's even over my start menu. If I restart eclipse, it's fine again, but after launching a couple java projects, it starts doing it again. Any suggestions?

Comment: Version is 2020-06 in case that's relevant.